# How to catch XML packets that ConsoleExport Firebug extension sends?

Tags: firefox, firebug, logging

I have installed [ConsoleExport](http://www.softwareishard.com/blog/consoleexport/) Firebug extension. I have enabled auto-export feature at `about:config` by setting `extensions.firebug.consoleexport.active` to `true`. I have opened a page with JavaScript error, for example http://www.random.org. I have enabled Firebug, reloaded the page. I can see the error in log:

```
uncaught exception: Error: Permission denied for <https://www.facebook.com> to get property Proxy.InstallTrigger
```

The [ConsoleExport](http://www.softwareishard.com/blog/consoleexport/) page says:

> You can also activate an auto-export feature that is sending
>   individual logs into specified server as XML packets.

I know I should set `extensions.firebug.consoleexport.serverURL` to server URL. I do not know how to catch XML packets that ConsoleExport sends.

For example, I know how to set up Apache on Mac, but what then? How to catch XML packets?

Environment:

- Mac OS X 10.7.2
- Firefox 8.0.1
- Firebug 1.8.4
- ConsoleExport 0.5b4

I have access to Windows and Linux machines, if the server that catches XML packets is easier to set up there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modified script fixing a problem with getting the posted data:

Note that the content-Type of the posted data is application/xml

```
<?php
  $filename = 'consoleexport.log';

  if (!$handle = fopen($filename, 'a'))
  {
    echo 'File "'.$filename.'" could not be opened';
    exit;
  }

  ob_start();
  $content = file_get_contents('php://input');
  $content .= "\n";
  ob_clean();

  if (!fwrite($handle, $content))
  {
    echo 'Can\'t write into file "'.$filename.'"';
    exit;
  }

  echo 'Done!';
  fclose($handle);
?>
```

Honza

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like it simply sends the XML data via an AJAX request to that URL.
So you need to define a script, that handles that XML data.

E.g. when you use PHP, you could set the `serverURL` preference to `http://localhost/handleFBConsoleOutput.php`. That script could then look like this:

```php
<?php
  $filename = '/path/to/log/file/consoleexport.log';

  if (!$handle = fopen($filename, 'a'))
  {
    echo 'File "'.$filename.'" could not be opened';
    exit;
  }

  ob_start();
  var_dump($_POST);
  $content = ob_get_contents();
  ob_clean();

  if (!fwrite($handle, $content))
  {
    echo 'Can\'t write into file "'.$filename.'"';
    exit;
  }

  echo 'Done!';
  fclose($handle);
?>
```

The code shown here writes a dump of all POST parameters. You might want to specify the exact parameter as output by replacing the `$content` variable by `$_POST['param_name']`, where `param_name` is the name of the parameter holding the XML contents, and remove the `ob_start(); ... ob_clean();` block.

As reference:
The same issue was asked at the [Firebug discussion group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebug/HkC9SBQjMUo).

Comment: Thanks for the effort, but looks like a line or two were wrong. :)